# Will Istio (or Service Mesh) reduce concurrent connections or cause port exhaustion？

Tags: kubernetes, istio

Istio will insert a proxy as the sidecar in my pod. But it's confusing me. Because I think it will reduce the number of concurrent connections and cause the problem of port exhaustion.

Am I right?